# iOS and android reader for djvu files that supports tabs

Tags: android, ios, djvu

I'm looking for an application on android and on ipod touch that will display djvu's AND has tabs at the top like xodo and good reader. Does one exist? The best I've found so far is djvu reader/totalreader but it doesn't have tabs that you can switch between two open documents.

Comment: I just found out that Ebook droid can display djvu's so it is the answer for android. Is there an answer for IOS?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Xodo, while not supported now, you can suggest/vote for djvu support here.
http://feedback.xodo.com/forums/241992-suggest-a-new-feature

Perhaps it will be added in a future version for iOS/Android/UWP.